# How to hide system controls on AVPictureInPictureController's float window?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, ios14, picture-in-picture

I want to hide these system controls on the iOS14 pip：

[image]

Any way I can do it?

Comment: please share your code for better understanding.

Comment: https://github.com/CaiWanFeng/CustomPictureInPicture

Comment: @无夜之星辰 This is the way to custom PictureInPicture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with **KVC**:

#### 1. Hide forward button and back button:

Swift:

```swift
pipController.setValue(1, forKey: "requiresLinearPlayback")
```

Objective-C:

```
[self.pipController setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"requiresLinearPlayback"]
```

#### 2. Hide progress bar, play button, forward button and back button:

Swift:

```swift
pipController.setValue(1, forKey: "controlsStyle")
```

Objective-C:

```objectivec
[self.pipController setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"controlsStyle"];
```

#### 3. Hide all the controls on the pip:

**Note: iOS16+ only**

Swift:

```swift
pipController.setValue(2, forKey: "controlsStyle")
```

Objective-C:

```objectivec
[self.pipController setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"controlsStyle"];
```

---

For more detail about custom picture-in-picture, you can take a look at my repository here:

https://github.com/CaiWanFeng/PiP

Comment: Will these techniques make it past App Review?

Answer (score 3):

You can hide at least the seek buttons via:

```
vc.requiresLinearPlayback = true
```

Where **vc** is your **AVPictureInPictureController** instance.

If you have already found a way how to hide the play button, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            //Hide the seekbar
            pipController?.requiresLinearPlayback = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        
        //Hide the play/pause controls
        pipController?.setValue(1, forKey: "controlsStyle")
```