# Change picture-in-picture forward/backward values in AVPictureInPictureController

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit

How can be changed playback (forward and backward) buttons values in `AVPictureInPictureController`?

My backward and forward buttons have 15 seconds value by default (screenshot from my app is attached), but I've found other apps has 10 seconds (for instance, Apple TV iOS app).

[image]

This [Apple forum discussion](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/21629?answerId=70701022#70701022) I've read that `AVPlayerViewController` adapts its capabilities and controls to the asset being played.

But it seems backward/forward values in PiP stay the same for all videos independent of duration in both my app and apps I've found. But I can't find the way to change them.

Comment: did you check this put value 0 to check whether icons will show or hide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67528832/how-to-hide-system-controls-on-avpictureinpicturecontrollers-float-window 
//Hide the play/pause controls
 pipController?.setValue(1, forKey: "controlsStyle")

https://community.bitmovin.com/t/ios-picture-in-picture-player-controls-visibility/1504